# Why did this mkdir not work properly?

Tags: centos, mkdir

Why did this `mkdir` not work properly?
The folder is strangely named as `{a`.

```
mkdir -p myfile/{a/a{1..10}, b/b{10..30}, c/c{1,2,3}}
```

[image]

Comment: My reading of the `Brace Expansion` section of the `bash` man page is that the space character after each comma is causing you trouble.  The examples there look like this: `mkdir /usr/local/src/bash/{old,new,dist,bugs}` - no spaces after the commas.  If you're using a different shell that supports spaces in brace expansions, please tag your question with the shell you're using.

Comment: Please don't post screnshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block]s so we can verify exactly what was run and the exact output

Comment: @SottoVoce remove the spaces work. Wouldn't allow the spaces make the life easier? Where can I read more about this? I'm new to linux.

Comment: Brace expansion of any kind like this is done by the shell, not by `mkdir`. You can use `echo` to help figure out what will happen.  Eg `echo {1..10}` will result in `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` This is useful when you want to work out which but if our expression isn't working. Eg: `echo mkdir -p myfile/{a/a{1..10}, b/b{10..30}, c/c{1,2,3}}`

Comment: @internet I'm glad it works.  As to why spaces aren't supported, I didn't write the C code in your shell that parses command lines, so it's impossible for me to answer.

Comment: @muru I think so, I'll read that now. EDIT. that is a good answer.

Comment: You can read about why this works this way here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html The spaces are parsed first and then the brances, meaning the line is split on spaces and then those parts parsed for brace expressions.